# tool "draw" not found for space "VIEW-3D

Tags: texturing

running into a weird problem that could very well be me being a noob. I am following along with blender guru tutorial on the anvil. He gets to a point where he selects texture paint mode and his cursor and window goes into paint mode. In my blender 2.80 however, nothing happens but a little exclamation mark and a yellow text along the bottom says

Tool "draw" not found for space "VIEW-3D

the weird thing is that other projects seem to work just fine. Does anyone have a fix for this as I had put in a bit of time already into the model texturing/sculpting restarting would suck. much thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 2):

Solving this issue (not exactly an issue) in Blender 2.80 is actually very simple.

Before opening the *Sculpting* tab, go to *Layout* tab and be sure that in the *Outliner*, the reverse triangle icon on the left side of your object name, is highlighted. It should be gray in dark theme.

If not, simply click on it and select your object. Then open *Sculpting* tab and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem in grease pencil blender 3.2 for the error message.

"Tool 'builtin.select_box' not found for space 'VIEW_3D'"

[image: https://i.imgur.com/UAw09qc.png]

This is blender's way of telling you you don't have any tool selected, so blender can't do anything.
To resolve the issue, **simply press T in the 3D view and click a tool option, the error should go away after that.**

[image: https://i.imgur.com/a0uN8pz.png]
[image: https://i.imgur.com/zEOOLQg.png]

Source: https://developer.blender.org/T98837, User: aVersionOfReality

Answer (score 0):

That also happened to me, but I found out that I was just me not selecting a brush. And that's what caused the error.

So just select a brush if blender already didn't select one.